# How do I know if my Tomcat supports Servlet 3.0 or not?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I am using Tomcat 6.33 and I am wondering how can I check if it supports Servlet 3.0 or El 2.2 or not?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can check by reading the Tomcat documentation - see the [Apache Tomcat Versions](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) page ... which lists the versions of the JSP and Servlet specs supported by each major version of Tomcat.

(Answer from the list: Tomcat 6.x supports Servlet 2.5 and JSP/EL 2.1)

---

If you want to find out the Servlet spec version at runtime, the [`ServletContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html) API has methods called `getMajorVersion()` and `getMinorVersion()` that should tell you.

I also [found](http://www.coderanch.com/t/425693/java-Web-Component-SCWCD/certification/servlet-jsp-version) this recipe for displaying various version numbers using a JSP:

```
Server info: <%= application.getServerInfo() %><br>
Servlet version: <%= application.getMajorVersion() %>.<%= application.getMinorVersion() %><br>
JSP version: <%= JspFactory.getDefaultFactory().getEngineInfo().getSpecificationVersion() %><br>
Java version: <%= System.getProperty("java.version") %><br>
```

Answer (score 7):

From http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html: Tomcat 6 supports Servlet 2.5

Answer (score 2):

Servlet 3.0 API is supported on Apache Tomcat 7.0.x onwords, [Apache Tomcat 7.0.65](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/servletapi/) being the actual release version.